# Finding dimension of a vector subspace/vectorspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ a vector space with dimension $5$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ and let $W$ a vector subspace of $V$ with dimension $2$. Define $S=\{T:V\rightarrow V \ |\  T \mbox{ is zero on W}\}$ where $T$ is a linear transformation.

It is clear that the $S$ is a vector subspace of vector space $L(V,V)$ where $L(V,V)=\{T:V\rightarrow V \ |\ T \mbox{ is a linear transformation}\}.$
How can I find the dimension of S?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $(w_1,w_2)$ is a basis of $W$. Since $(w_1,w_2)$ is linearly independent in $V$, it can be extended to a basis $(w_1,w_2,v_1,v_2,v_3)$ of $V$. Letting $\mathcal{M}(T)$ denote $T$ in matrix form with respect to this basis, we have:
$$
\mathcal{M}(T) = \left(\begin{matrix}
Tw_1 & Tw_2 & Tv_1 & Tv_2 & Tv_3
\end{matrix}\right)
= \left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
0 & 0 & a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
0 & 0 & a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \\
0 & 0 & a_4 & b_4 & c_4 \\
0 & 0 & a_5 & b_5 & c_5 \\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
It then becomes obvious that this is the same as the set of linear transformations from $span\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ to $V$, which has dimension 15.